# Regex that matches 2 patterns at once or SED in Applescript that matches both

Tags: regex, sed, applescript

I have 2 types of string user inputs and i am trying to match them by using 1 regex.
So far i've been doing this with 2 regexes but i would like to combine them in one that matches both strings .. if that's possible.
The match i am looking for is: `617251, 617076, 985922, 147721`

First User Input (string):

```
JEANS
Blue-Denim
6607020201
617076
HOSEKNLA
Oliv
6909020002
985922
ROCKWBKU
Rot
6919020006
147721
BLAZER
rot
```

I am matching this one with `(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)`

Second User Input (string):

```
a Ecru  617 251 64  I   b Lagune    617 076 64
c Gelb  985 922 64  I   d Weiß  147 721 64
asdasfas
```

I am matching this one with:`(\d){3} (\d){3}` but can't remove the `space` of the match result without replacing.

If that's not possible my other idea is by using SED in AppleScript that clears both type of strings to match the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lookarounds work for the first pattern, you could use 2 capturing groups where the second group matches an optional space.

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3}) ?(\d{3})(?!\d)
```

In parts

- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a digit directly to the left
- `(\d{3})` Capture **group 1**, match 3 digits
- `<code> ?(\d{3})` Match optional space and capture 3 digits in **group 2**
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead, assert not a digit directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ag9Pgk/1)

Comment: How would the Regex change if i have to match again both strings together but the second one is without space like this : a Ecru  61725164  I   b Lagune    61707664 c Gelb  98592264  I   d Weiß  14772164 asdasfas. Thank you for helping me. Really appritiated !

Comment: @OutOfTouch do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/0s2udE/1

Comment: Unfortinately not exactly. The second regex matches correctly `a Ecru ` **617251** `64 I b Lagune ` **617076** `64 c Gelb ` **985922** `64 I d Weiß ` **147721** `64` when there are no spaces..but of the first string wrongly matches `JEANS
Blue-Denim`
**660702** `0201` 
**617076** 
`HOSEKNLA
Oliv` 
**690902** `0002`
**985922** 
`ROCKWBKU
Rot`. From the first string it should match only **617076** **985922** and skip the numbers 6 digits longer.

Comment: @OutOfTouch If the second pattern has the right matches except for the upper longer than 6 digits values, you could optionally match 2 digits https://regex101.com/r/J8IJxM/1

Comment: @OutOfTouch Of you can state that you want to match when not followed by 4 digits `(?<!\d)(\d{3}) ?(\d{3})(?!\d{4})` https://regex101.com/r/7oDXUw/1

Comment: Thank you for all the info. I've done many test in order to implement the right Regex for my needs..and thanks to you i got what i needed :). It's still difficult for me to catch the logic of Regexes but i am one step closer after solving this problem :).

Answer (score 1):

For matching you should consider using `grep` instead of `sed`.

Here is a working `grep` on OSX. Note use of `\<` and `\>` for word boundaries as it is evident from your sample data that you don't really need lookbehind and lookahead assertions.

```
grep -oE '\<[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3}\>' file
```

```
617076
985922
147721
617 251
617 076
985 922
147 721
```

An equivalent `sed` on OSX would be this:

```
sed -nE '/[[:<:]][0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3}[[:>:]]/p' file
```

Comment: I've been using it like this: `set FinalString to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of RawStringResult & " | grep -oE '[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3}'"` and for the First user input string: `JEANS
Blue-Denim
6607020201
617076
HOSEKNLA
Oliv` it matches **660702** and **617076** . It should not match **660702** since it's a part of more than 6 digits number. Considering the second string .. it works fine. Thank you !

Comment: But I suggested `grep -oE '\<[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3}\>' that uses word boundaries then it won't match `660702`

Comment: Yes. It works now. Sorry..i understood your comment in a wrong way. Thank you for helping me. I am gonna dig deeper in sed and grep. Have to know how this language works in details.